# My Customer data is being truncated when added to my List

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, dao, truncate

First things first. In my main : The connection is successful the DROP is successful; and the creation of the table to my understanding is successful. However when I get to the insertingCustomers part, things start go awry.

```
private void run() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ApplicationException {
        LOG.info("Running");

        //Class.forName(properties.getProperty(DbConstants.DB_DRIVER_KEY));
        LOG.info("Driver loaded");

        connect();

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        try {
            customerDao.drop(); //Good I think.

            customerDao.create(); //Good I think.

            insertCustomers(); //Problems.

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
```

The Table being created with customerDao.create() looks like this:
Side question am I assigning the Customer's id as the primary key properly here?

```
    @Override
    public void create() throws SQLException {
        String sql = String.format(
                "create table %s(" // 1
                        + "%s VARCHAR(9), " // 2
                        + "%s VARCHAR(20), " // 3
                        + "%s VARCHAR(20), " // 4
                        + "%s VARCHAR(20), " // 5
                        + "%s VARCHAR(20), " // 6
                        + "%s VARCHAR(7), " // 7
                        + "%s VARCHAR(14), " // 8
                        + "%s VARCHAR(20), " // 9
                        + "%s DATE,"        //10
                        + "primary key (%s) )", // 11
                tableName, // 1
                Fields.ID.getName(), // 2
                Fields.FIRST_NAME.getName(), // 3
                Fields.LAST_NAME.getName(), // 4
                Fields.STREET.getName(), // 5
                Fields.CITY.getName(), // 6
                Fields.POSTAL_CODE.getName(), // 7
                Fields.PHONE.getName(), // 8
                Fields.EMAIL.getName(), // 9
                Fields.JOIN_DATE.getName(), //10
                Fields.ID.getName()); // 11
        LOG.debug(sql);
        super.create(sql);
    }
```

And the Fields are as follows:

```
public enum Fields {

        ID("Id", "Integer", 9, 1), //
        FIRST_NAME("firstName", "VARCHAR", 20, 2), //
        LAST_NAME("lastname", "VARCHAR", 20, 3), //
        STREET("Steet", "VARCHAR", 20, 4), //
        CITY("City", "VARCHAR", 10, 5), //
        POSTAL_CODE("postalCode", "VARCHAR", 7, 6), //
        PHONE("phone", "VARCHAR", 14, 7), //
        EMAIL("email", "VARCHAR", 30, 8), //
        JOIN_DATE("joinDate", "DATE", -1, 9); //

        private final String name;
        private final String type;
        private final int length;
        private final int column;

        Fields(String name, String type, int length, int column) {
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
            this.length = length;
            this.column = column;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getLength() {
            return length;
        }

        public int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll level with you I'm somewhat new to JDBC and SQL and I'm not sure why my JOIN_DATE Field has a length of -1; some example code we got had a BIRTH_DAY length of -1. Perhaps that's why things are being truncated. More on that now.

So after I create my Table I try to use the InsertCustomers() method to add to my table. For clarity I'm reading my Customer information from a text file. It works and the List DATA is filled properly.

```
private void insertCustomers() throws SQLException, ApplicationException {
        File customers_data_file = new File(CUSTOMER_DATA);

        List<Customer> DATA = CustomerReader.read(customers_data_file);

        try {
            for (Customer customer : DATA) {
                customerDao.add(customer);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This then goes to my customerDao.add() method where the exception is being thrown.

```
public void add(Customer customer) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Connection connection = database.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = String.format(
                    "insert into %s values(" // 1 tableName
                            + "'%s', " // 2 StudentId
                            + "'%s', " // 3 FirstName
                            + "'%s', " // 4 LastName
                            + "'%s', " // 5 Street
                            + "'%s', " // 6 City
                            + "'%s', " // 7 PostalCode
                            + "'%s', " // 8 Phone
                            + "'%s', " // 9 Email
                            + "'%s')", // 10 JoinDate
                    tableName, 
                    customer.getId(),
                    customer.getFirstName(),
                    customer.getLastName(),
                    customer.getStreet(),
                    customer.getCity(),
                    customer.getPostalCode(),
                    customer.getPhone(),
                    customer.getEmailAddress(),
                    customer.getJoinedDateString());

            LOG.debug(sql);
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        } finally {
            close(statement);
        }
    }
```

One other thing that just occurred to me; is the method I'm using to convert my joinedDate to a string might be causing problems see below; but I'd be mystified as to how.

```
public String getJoinedDateString() {
        if (joinedDate == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String result = joinedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        return result;
    }
```

And as soon as the line: statement.executeUpdate(sql);   executes I get this error:

> insert into A01045801_Customer values('1', 'Fred', 'Fish', '5707 Sidley St', 'Burnaby', 'V5J 5E6', '(604) 433-5004', 'fredfish@imperial.net', '2008-03-22')
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   Shutting down
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.

Sorry it's quite a bit of code I just read a few other peoples posts to see if my question was asked & answered and I didn't seem to find answers; and many people requested more info on that person's code. I guess I figured I'd supply all the necessary material.

Thanks :)

Comment: Your email field is 20 and you try to write more than that. Also your lengths in SQL are very different from the Java code, including defining the id as text in SQL and integer in code.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Bloody hell I must have miss counted earlier; thanks for spotting that X'D

With regards to the id Integer vs String in my notes I have DataBase types as:
integer(size),int(size),smallint(size),tinyint(size), decimal(size,d), Char(size), varchar(size), date(yyyymmdd), datetime(mm/dd/yyyy) for MS-SQL.

Am I wrong to use these?


I was thinking of making id type CHAR of 9 to force it to be 9 long.

Comment: @Mike_1234 Only use `CHAR` for fixed width string data. Use an `int` for numeric data, it saves space.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please learn about prepared statements and don't concatenate (or 'format') values into a query string.